# How do I recreate this shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been at this shape for a while now and still can't seem to reproduce it. :( A helping hand anyone?

A fellow Blenderer gave me these instructions but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. :s

---

"Here's a rough guide for the general shape.  You will have to play around with the faces to get it to look just right...
Add Mesh: Math Function - Regular solid. (Add-On : Add Mesh Extra Objects)
Dodecahedron: Vertex Truncation 1.0
• No Snub
• Dual OFF
Remove extra edges inside pentagram faces:
select one edge, then Select Similar: Length - RMB: Dissolve edges

Select Pentagram face - select similar for all
Inset faces : I , slightly to create a corner support for the subdivision.
Inset faces again for the inner circle.
subdivide edges 1 
vertex mode: Smooth Vertices 2.5,  steps 1.   (to create a circular face)
Face mode: inset - slightly, extrude out, scale in, inset (edge loop to sharpen the edges)

Select a triangle, then Select Similar: Area
Inset slightly to firm up the outside edge, 
Inset again and scale in by Median Point
You'll have to play around with the triangles to get the shape right.

Apply a subdivision modifier set to 2."

---

[image]

EDIT: This is how far I've managed to come with the instructions given. Smoothing 2.5 with a Repeat of 1, as suggested doesn't create a circular face.

[image]

Comment: How far are you able to get? Can you send a picture of what you have so far? (preferably in edit mode with no subdivision modifier active)

Comment: I've added an "edit" above so you can check out what I have so far.

Comment: @ObscureGuy could you please edit your post and use a ore descriptive title. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Edit: The 'mesh mode view' is actually viewport wireframe view and does not display all the edges and vertices you should be able to see in Edit mode. I would suggest opening the attached blend file to take a closer look.*

I've made this visual guide which I hope helps more than the explanation you provided in your post. The mesh is displayed in three states; edit mode, with the subdivision modifier visible and without.

(Since I'm not using the Math meshing addon, I'm using an ico sphere with an extra step to generate the required shape).

I've also attached the blend file, so you can see how it's set up precisely.

As a general guideline, you'll likely want to use insets only. Smoothing in edit mode isn't required since the Subdivision Surface modifier will display all edges as smoothed, unless you either crease them or add edge loops close by. Both options will sharpen your edges.

Using insets also means that your mesh topology likely will be (almost) quads only. This makes it easier to later edit mesh features, like changing the scale of edge loops or moving things around. You can make complex shapes with subdivision surface modifiers, while still having a relatively simple mesh.

As for scaling the inset faces, you're generally going to use Median Point and Individual Origins. Controlling their depth can be done using median point and scaling; the size of the faces themself perpendicular to their normals uses scaling along individual origin.

My resulting shape:

### [image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you loads!! Really appreciate the amount of work you put in trying to explain this as clear as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Start by adding an Ico Sphere with Subdivisions set to 1. Then add a Bevel modifier with the Only Vertices checkbox selected, and increase the Width.
- Apply the Bevel modifier.
- Go into edit mode (Tab), select all vertices (A) and merge by distance (Alt+M, By Distance).
- Go into face select mode (number 3).
- Select a triangle, then select similar polygon sides (Shift+G, Polygon Sides).
- Insert new faces into selected Faces (I), then move the mouse to make the new triangles a bit smaller, then click to confirm.
- Change the Pivot Point to Individual Origins.
- Extrude (E) the newly generated triangles, and move the mouse to move them inwards, then click to confirm.
- Select a pentagon, then select similar polygon sides (Shift+G, Polygon Sides).
- Insert new faces into selected Faces (I), then move the mouse to make
  the new pentagons a bit smaller, then click to confirm.
- Extrude (E) the newly generated pentagons, and move the mouse to move them outwards, then click to confirm. Go into object mode (Tab) and add a subsurf modifier (Ctrl+1).
- Shade Smooth (F3, Shade Smooth)

Comment: Hi. The edit I posted above is not a reply to this, it's just to show how far I've managed to come with the instructions given as detailed in my first post. I'll try yours now and see how it goes.